# Strange behavior with with kohana orm find_all() within foreach

Tags: php, mysql, orm, foreach, kohana

I'm a bit irritated why the second Code throws an Exception and the first not.
self::ID_FALLBACK is 1,
There are 2 or more Rows in Sections with id 1, 2...; all with Sectiongroup_id = 1

There is one Row in Sectiongroup with id 1

This works without any Problems:

```
public static function getSections(){
    // select groups with sections
    foreach(ORM::factory('Sectiongroup')->find_all() as $grp){
        $s = $grp->sections->where('id', '>', self::ID_FALLBACK)->find_all()->as_array('id', 'name');
        count($s) && $sections[$grp->name] = $s;
    }
    return $sections;
}
```

Next throws:
`Cannot use object of type Model_Sectiongroup as array` in Line `count($s) && $section..`

```
public static function getSections(){
    // select groups with sections
    $sections = ORM::factory('Sectiongroup');
    foreach($sections->find_all() as $grp){
        $s = $grp->sections->where('id', '>', self::ID_FALLBACK)->find_all()->as_array('id', 'name');
        count($s) && $sections[$grp->name] = $s;
    }
    return $sections;
}
```

Same error with 2 rows in Sectiongroup what should be an array now:

```
public static function getSections(){
    // select userdefined groups with sections
    $sections = ORM::factory('Sectiongroup');
    foreach($sections->find_all()->as_array() as $grp){
        $s = $grp->sections->where('id', '>', self::ID_FALLBACK)->find_all()->as_array('id', 'name');
        count($s) && $sections[$grp->name] = $s;
    }
    return $sections;
}
```

Whats that for a strange behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first (working) example, you never explicitly define the `$sections` array, and when you first write `$sections[$grp->name] = $s`, PHP creates the `$sections` **array** for you.

On your last two examples, you explicitly declare `$sections` to the return value of `ORM::factory()`, more specifically, an object subclass of `ORM` with which you cannot use the array subscript (`[]`) notation with.

Comment: That means, this Script is in fact a Hack and would normally not work?
And means further it is not recommended to do so?

Comment: Not at all, and there is an easy fix: You can either choose to use a different variable name for the results of `ORM::factory`, or simply declare the `ORM::factory()->find_all()` directly in the `foreach` loop like the first example does.